Min/ Max Elevation per Polygon (Delaware)
I need to find the min/ max elevation per pressure zone (polygon layer). I'm struggling to find good input data - DEM or Elevation or... what should I use? Also, are there available tools in ArcGIS Pro that will allow me to easily find what the min/ max elevations are for these zones?

There's Aster DEM

For finding an appropriate elevation dataset try asking on Open Data Stack Exchange. The size of your pressure zones and other use case details will determine what is/isn't an appropriate resolution for elevation data. If 10m or 30m resolution is ok, that is available from USGS through the National Map Downloader.
Once you have an elevation raster you can use Zonal Statistics as Table to calculate the min and max, and then (if needed) join that data back up to your polygon layer for visualization purposes.

Huge help, thank you!

You're welcome. Stack Exchange tip: if an answer is helpful you (as the question asker) can accept it, and anyone can upvote helpful answers. This way if a question gets multiple answers the most useful ones will filter to the top.
